# Чередования

Tags: фонетика

Как легко различить историческое чередование от позиционного?  Никак не могу разобраться. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Если в двух словах, то позиционные чередования объясняются в рамках ныне действующих общих законов (обычно - фонетических), а исторические - законами, которые ныне утратили силу.

Подробно - например здесь:
http://helena2012.nichost.ru/fonetika/35-cheredovanie-zvukov

Answer (score 1):

Если вообще не касаться общих законов, то можно объяснить совсем просто.

Вот слово "мороз", его можно прочитать "орфографически" - м о р о з, но нужно читать м Λ  р о с, по правилам орфоэпии,  с учетом фонетического чередования О/Λ  и З/С. А вот в словах "подруга - дружить - друзья" чередование Г/Ж/З является историческим, так как оно обязательно озвучивается в современной речи.

Также обратим внимание, что в этом случае звуки стоят в сильной позиции (перед гласной), а фонетическое чередование всегда связано со слабыми позициями